# Path planning using 2D array

Tags: c++, loops, path

The problem require user input the size of 2D grid. Then input each of the entries.

Like this:

```
5 5

-1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 0 0 0 -1
-1 1 -1 0 -1
-1 0 0 -2 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

Then the output should be 3. Which is the smallest path from the starting point " 1 " to end point "-2". Where the " -1 " are the obstacle, 0 as a feasible space.

The method given by the instructor is:

first, locate the starting point " 1 " . The filling its feasible space 4-neighbours ( left, right, up and down) with " 2 "

Then, repeat the steps by filling the neighbours feasible space by " 3 " and so on.

When the possible feasible space is " -2 ". Stop and print out the minimum steps number.

I will try to write it out.

1. Find the starting point.

   ```
   -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
   -1 0 0 0 -1
   -1 **1** -1 0 -1
   -1 0 0 -2 -1
   -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
   ```
2. Replace it neighbours "0" by " 2 " and find the other possible feasible space.

   ```
   -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
   -1 **2** **0** 0 -1
   -1 1 -1 0 -1
   -1 **2** **0** -2 -1
   -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
   ```
3. Repeat the steps.

   ```
   -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
   -1 2 3 **0** -1
   -1 1 -1 0 -1
   -1 2 3 **-2** -1
   -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
   ```

As the neighbour is " -2 " . So the shortest path is 3.

```
// Find the Starting point " 1 ".
```

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_SIZE = 100;


///////// DO NOT MODIFY ANYTHING ABOVE THIS LINE /////////

// IMPORTANT:  Do NOT change any of the function headers already provided to you
//             It means that you will need to use the function headers as is


// You may implement additional functions here

bool NextFill(int(&map)[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE], int n)
{
 const int offx = { -1, 0, 0, 1 };
 const int offy = { 0, -1, 1, 0 }
 bool found = false;
 for (int x = 0; x != MAX_SIZE; ++x) {
     for (int y = 0; y != MAX_SIZE; ++y) {
         if (map[x][y] == n) {
             for (int i = 0; i != 4) {
                 auto& neighbor = map[x + offx[i]][y + offy[i]];

                 if (neighbor == -1) {  } 
                 else if (neighbor == -2) { found = true; } 
                 else if (neighbor == 0) { neighbor = n + 1; } 

             }
         }
     }
 }
 return found;
}

// Function: find the smallest number of steps to go from the starting point
//           to the destination in a given map.
//
// Input: int map[][]: 2D-array map
//        int map_h: the height of the map
//        int map_w: the width of the map
// Output: return true if a path is found, and store the smallest number of
//                      steps taken in &num_steps (pass-by-reference)
//         return false if there is no path
// ==============================================================
bool FindPath(int map[][MAX_SIZE], int map_h, int map_w, int& num_steps)
{
 // ==========================
 int time = 0;
 if (NextFill(map, time))
     return true;
 else
     return false;
}

///////// DO NOT MODIFY ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE /////////

// Function: main function
// ==============================================================
int main()
{
 int map_h;
 int map_w;
 cin >> map_h >> map_w;

 int map[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];

 // initialize map
 for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
     for (int j = 0; j < MAX_SIZE; j++)
         map[i][j] = -1;

 // read map from standard input
 for (int i = 0; i < map_h; i++)
     for (int j = 0; j < map_w; j++)
         cin >> map[i][j];

 int steps;
 // print to screen number of steps if a path is found, otherwise print "No"
 if (FindPath(map, map_h, map_w, steps))
     cout << steps << endl;

 else
     cout << "No" << endl;

}
```

My code can find the starting point and find its possible feasible space as well as replace it by " 2 ". But i have no idea of find the possible feasible space of mine " 2 " and replace it by " 3 " and so on.

However, I can't include any header in my program.

Thanks for reading a long long question :)!

Comment: You might look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have either to store in some queue your open nodes, or fill from whole map each time:

```
bool NextFill(int (&map)[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE], int n)
{
    const int offx = {-1, 0, 0, 1};
    const int offy = {0, -1, 1, 0}
    bool found = false;
    for (int x = 0; x != MAX_SIZE; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y != MAX_SIZE; ++y) {
            if (map[x][y] == n) {
                 for (int i = 0; i != 4) {
                     auto& neighbor = map[x + offx[i]][y + offy[i]];

                     if (neighbor == -1) { /*Nothing*/ } // wall
                     else if (neighbor == -2) { found = true; } // Found
                     else if (neighbor == 0) { neighbor = n + 1; } // unvisited
                     // else {/*Nothing*/} // Already visited.
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Comment: How about if there is no valid path? for example : there are no " -2 "?
Sorry for late reply...

Comment: You might detect it with a bool flag set for `neighbor == 0`.

Comment: Sorry, i have no idea, can you help with debug ? I even can't use the given  ```FindPath``` function . That means your code is powerful but this is an assignment ... haha

Comment: I edited the post and posted my code here sorry for annoying